# how to flush changes to persistent manager

Tags: google-app-engine

The scenario is a update entity where i write code as follows:

```
    try {
            pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
            BloodDonor bloodDonor = pm.getObjectById(BloodDonor.class,
                    bean.getBloodDonorSeq());
            bloodDonor.setFirstName(firstName);
finally {
            try {
                if (pm != null && pm.isClosed() == false)
                    pm.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.severe("Exception in finally of execute of updateDonor");
            }
            log.info("end of updateDonor");
        }
```

So, when it will hit the finally block on close of pm the changes will be written to datastore. My question is in a certain situation say i want to rollback whatever i did in the try block before closing the pm then how to do that? in other words, if i want to nullify the effect of try block then how do i do notify pm to clear all?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [transaction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) to accomplish what you want to do here.

Comment: yes i am aware of transactions. Any way without using transactions?